# Powershell script to check status of user in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Powershell script to check status of user accounts are enabled or disabled using a text file which has names ( first name and last name)

I am trying to find out if a user account is enabled or disabled in AD from a list of users which is a text file using powershell.

I have tried to get the code to fetch names from a list of users in a text file and check if their accounts are enabled or disabled in AD. But the code below is giving an error message.

```
Get-Content -Path users.txt |
ForEach-Object {
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$_)" |
Select-Object -Property samaccountname,enabled
}
```

I think its something to do with the samaccountname as I just have the names in simple text format ( firstname lastname).

Comment: does `users.txt` contains a list of samAccountName? what exactly the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is in "FirstName Lastname" format you can try this:

```
$ResultList = Get-Content -Path users.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$_)" | Select-Object -Property samaccountname,enabled
}
$ResultList | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Using [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx) would make it fairly likely that it would find multiple matches for each account. That may or may not be acceptable, depending on the requirements.

Comment: That would also depend on the input data accuracy. Up to the OP to decide.

Comment: No, not even that. ANR will return partial matches. The documentation describes how it does that. Let's say you have a "John James" and a "James Johnson" in your organization. If you search for `(anr=John James)`, it will return both, even though your input data is accurate and only one is an exact match.

Comment: I'm not saying that ANR should not be used. It's just something the OP needs to be aware of.

Comment: How do I export the same to CSV format ?
I tired 
Get-Content -Path users.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$_)" |
    Select-Object -Property samaccountname,enabled | Export-csv "Results.csv"
}

But its not working

Comment: See above. Make sure the folder path exists when you export

Answer (score 0):

If the names in the textfile compare to the DisplayName property of your AD users, you can do this:

```
# read the text file as an array of strings
$userNames = Get-Content -Path users.txt
# get the list of users where the DisplayName property corresponds to an item in the array.
# since the DisplayName property is not returned by Get-ADUser by default, we have to specify
# what properties we need returned here.
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, SamAccountName, Enabled | 
Where-Object { $userNames -contains $_.DisplayName } |
Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Enabled
```

If you are not sure about the names corresponding with the DisplayName property, perhaps splitting the values into first and lastname might be another idea:

```
# read the textfile and create an array of objects with properties FirstName and LastName.
Get-Content -Path D:\users.txt | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'FirstName'; Expression = {($_ -split ' ',2)[0].Trim()}},
              @{Name = 'LastName';  Expression = {($_ -split ' ',2)[1].Trim()}} |
ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($_.FirstName)' -and Surname -eq '$($_.LastName)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        $user | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, Enabled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the users.txt contains only a list of first names and last names single space separated, you can do the following:

```
switch -Regex -File users.txt {
    '^(\S+)\s(.*)$' { 
        Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($Matches[1])' -and Surname -eq '$($Matches[2])'" |
            Select-Object SamAccountName,Enabled
    }
}
```

This utilizes the switch statement, which will generally be more efficient than using `Get-Content` on a file and processing `Foreach-Object` per pipeline object.

`^(\S+)\s(.*)$` is a regex string. `\S+` is one or more consecutive, non-space characters. `\s` is one space character. `.*` is zero or more consecutive characters. `^` matches the beginning of a line. `$` matches the end of a line. Each match is stored in the automatic variable `$Matches`. Using `()` around characters creates capture groups, which can be retrieved from the `$Matches` collection. `$Matches[1]` is group 1 (first name with no spaces), and `$Matches[1]` is group 2 (last name: everything after the first space).

If a line does not match the regex string, that line will be ignored.

---

Speaking strictly about command performance, the `-Filter` containing a query other than `*` will almost always be faster than relying solely on `Where-Object`. However, there is a point where one `Get-ADUser -Filter *` query is going to be time-wise more efficient than thousands of faster `Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq 'data'"` queries. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The regex you use however does not match lastnames with two or more words like `Pepe Ay y Olé` for instance..

Comment: First names could also have the same issue. A better delimiter should be used to deal with that problem. If we only care about last name spaces, then the second capture group could just become `.*`.